# OS-X|Genemotion emulator- ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemon

Tags: android, genymotion

Hi I am using genymotion emulator in mac os-x10.11.4.

While running adb pull command I am getting **failed to start daemon** error.

I read various SO questions but none of them are helping out.

Here is what I am doing!

Path -

```
cd/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
./adb shell
root@vbox86p - adb pull /data/data/com.something.android/sample.db


Error - ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADB binary shipped with your Genymotion looks incompatible with the ADB binary shipped in your Android Studio. To fix that:

- Stop any running Genymotion device
- Kill any adb process running
- Open Genymotion settings, go to the ADB tab
- Select "Use Android Studio SDK tools"
- Enter the path to your Android Studio SDK